# declarar variable (pedir espacio en memoria estática) en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c

En este código estoy declarando una variable en tiempo de ejecución,`a[]` (reservando espacio en memoria estática).

Tengo entendido que no es posible hacerlo o estoy confundido con los conceptos?

Compila y ejecuta bien aparentemente.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main(){
int cantidad,i,j,temp;

printf("Ingrese cantidad de valores a ordenar: ");
scanf("%d",&cantidad);

int a[cantidad];
//int* a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int[cantidad]));

for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
    printf("Ingrese el valor en %d: ",i);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}

for (i=1;i<cantidad;i++){
    for(j=0;j<cantidad-1;j++){
        if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
            temp=a[j];a[j]=a[j+1];a[j+1]=temp;}
}
}
printf("\n");

for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++){
printf("valor ordenado en %d es %d \n",i,a[i]);}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tengo entendido que no es posible hacerlo o estoy confundido con los conceptos?

El array no se carga en la memoria estática sino en la pila. Y es lo que se conoce como **VLA** (Variable Length Array) o array de longitud variable y no es una característica soportada por el estándar de C (creo que a partir de C11). Hay compiladores que lo soportan pero no es conveniente abusar de ello... menos aun sin validar su tamaño (imagina que el usuario introduce 1000000... desbordas la pila y el programa muere).

Es preferible usar memoria dinámica:

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(cantidad * sizeof(int));
```

Y para liberar la memoria cuando ya no sea necesaria:

```
free(a);
```

El resto del código no será necesario modificarlo.

Answer (score 1):

aludiendo a lo comentado por *eferion*, la versión correcta es:

```
int *a;
a=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
a=(int*)realloc(a,sizeof(int)*cantidad);
```

.

Answer (score 0):

tienes que crear un pointer a enteros, y luego, redimensionarlo por cada posición

```
int *a;
a=(int*)realloc(a,sizeof(int)*cantidad);
```

Comment: Si llamas a `realloc` pasando un puntero sin inicializar el programa te va a dar problemas por todos lados... ¿estas seguro de que has probado esas dos líneas de código funcionan como esperas?

Comment: si, y funciona perfectamente; pero tienes razón, para evitar cualquier problema, se le asigna memoria al puntero primero.